# Which is the Toyota specific toolset name in order to change head gasket on a ᴠᴠᴛ‑i engine?

Tags: toyota, tools, cylinder-head, yaris, tool-identification

My mechanic told me reassembling the cylinder‑head for a [ᴠᴠᴛ‑i engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VVT-i) requires specific Toyota tools.

His car part provider isn’t selling them, and as he is unable to use a computer or a mobile phone (and thus Internet), he can’t look elsewhere online.
On my end, I got my driver license only one year ago, and van renting compating requires drivers licenses to be older than 5 years (not by law but based on business decisions) (the nearest Toyota repair shop being more than 200Km away).

So we agreed that it would be Ok if I buy the tools myself along the manual to use them.
But in order to look at the tools online, I need the names of what to buy.

So which is the specific tool required for reassembling cylinders‑heads of [2ꜱ‑ᴢꜰᴇ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota_SZ_engine) engines ?

The car is a December 2007 Yaris 1297cc.

Comment: Have you considered getting a better mechanic?  These days a mechanic who is unable to use technology is not really very useful.

Comment: @jwh20 back to problem 1 : renting a van for moving the car elsewhere only 1 year after getting the driving license for the 1ˢᵗ time. Local car towers don’t run for more than 100Km. So even towing isn’t possible whatever the price.

Comment: Get the manual then you will have the names **and** part numbers for the tools...

Comment: @SolarMike it’s not in the manual. It should be in the manuel sold with the tools. Additionnaly, neither I or the mechanic read Italiano.

Comment: None of this makes any sense. Toyota is an international company. You can get the manuals in any language you want (including English). Did your so-called "mechanic" take the head off BEFORE discovering he needed "special tools" to reassemble it? Looking at a couple of web sites, the only "special tool" you need is a torx screwdriver set, which you can buy anywhere on line - but how did your mechanic take it apart without that? Did he just use a blowtorch and a hammer or something … ???

Comment: @alephzero the point is of course he warmed me before putting it apart. the special tool isn’t needed to put it apart, but for reassembling there’s no mark and the ᴠᴠᴛ‑i system is a sytem which tune valve timing settings at the level of the transmission and between the camshaft through varying oil pressure. The risk is if this setting system incorrectly it may tune valve timings to the point of breaking the engine, this is why special tools are required.

Comment: Every car manufacturer workshop manual that I have worked with ( and that inludes Toyota) givesthe name and part designation of the special tools along with when and how to use them in many languages. This now sounds like you expect us to purchase, read, and then copy out the manual because you don’t want to get one...

Comment: @SolarMike : no as the manual would be needed for knowing how to use the tools. But you found a point : the mechanic repairs a Toyota only once a year, so he have nothing specific to Toyota (unless me with what I bought with the car). On my end, I’m de‑facto not allowed to rent a car to got at Toyota (otherwise they refuse to talk to non professionals about such questions over the phone).

Comment: Year, Model and engine liters please.

Comment: @Moab 2007 and for everything else, I gave you the reference engine model wikipedia page in the question.

Comment: Thanks, its better to post full info in the body of the question, not in a Link. I still don't know what model the car is, this helps me do research.

Comment: @Moab just added the reference in the last line of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think that your so-called mechanic is talking about being a Toyota-specific part is the Crankshaft Pulley Holding Tool which is OEM part# [09213-54015](https://toyota.service-solutions.com/en-US/Pages/ItemDetail.aspx?SKU=09213-54015-01), it's not exactly some arcane unicorn baby tooth that is hard to get a hold of. It's applicable to a wide range of Toyota engines and is *easily* available from either Toyota themselves (see earlier link) or other [aftermarket tool suppliers](https://www.lasertools.co.uk/product/4898) - complete with plenty of documentation with how to use them.

Although I have to agree @SolarMike any Toyota workshop manual worth the paper it's printed on should have the information of how to use these tools (and which tools are required).

As an aside, the idea of a professional mechanic expecting you (the customer) to buy a tool that realistically they should be obtaining as part of doing business is shocking - and the notion that they are somehow incapable of obtaining this themselves is so absurd I almost spat my coffee out. It's a fricking *Toyota* not some rare and exotic car that was only made for two years in a shed in Elbonia. So it's not that he *can't* get the appropriate tool, he *won't*.

Your "mechanic" knows he's got you over a barrel - your car is in pieces at his place and you would have a load of hassle and expense to get it elsewhere. And they are damn sure making the most of it! You might not be able to get out of being screwed over on this job but I wouldn't be trusting this place with any future work!

Comment: Finally found the 2 required tools for an astonishing minimal amount of 290€ or more while calling an other mechanic. Don’t remember the name, but I’m unwilling to pay.